# Python signal: reading return from signal handler function

Tags: python, return-value, signals

Simple question; How do you read the return value of a function that is called as a signal handler?

```
import signal

def SigHand(sig, frm):
    return 'SomeValue'

signal.signal(signal.SIGCHLD, SigHand)
signal.pause()
```

Is there a way to read the return value `'SomeValue'` other than setting it as a global?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a simple class with a return value attribute.

```
>>> import signal
>>> class SignalHandler(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.retval = None
...     def handle(self, sig, frm):
...         self.retval = sig
... 
>>> s = SignalHandler()
>>> s.retval
>>> signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, s.handle)
0
>>> signal.alarm(1)
0
>>> s.retval
14
```